# Easyrtc call duration logging/ peer-to-peer processing

Tags: java, websocket, webrtc, easyrtc

I'm using easyrtc to establish a webrtc connection between clients through a mainly java/html based web app. I'd like to build in the functionality for the duration of the call to be logged, and need to understand the following:

Is there already built in functionality within easyrtc to pass this data via websockets to signal server?
If not: Would I need to use a framework where the client submits a data packet at intervals where the call is active? How is this complicated with client side timer accuracy and security?

The intention is that call length will translate to payment from one peer to the other, hence must be immune to simple things like the client closing the window. As such I suspect I will need to keep as much as possible on server-side, but on that note - how secure would this 'call active' data send through either websockets/ajax be if I chose the latter option?

Lots of questions, many thoughts, guidance would really help!

Comment: Did you ever find your answer? I am interested in doing the same...